# Regular expression to extract all sentences that start and end with the same word

Tags: python, regex

Given a string of sentences, I need to extract a list of all of the sentences which start and end with the same word.

e.g.

```py
# sample text
text = "This is a sample sentence. well, I'll check that things are going well. another sentence starting with another. ..."

# required result
[
 "well, I'll check that things are going well",
 "another sentence starting with another"
]
```

How can I make the match using back references and also capture the full sentence?

I have tried the following regex but it's not working.

```py
re.findall("^[a-zA-Z](.*[a-zA-Z])?$", text)
```

Comment: Why does it need to be using a regex?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is the requirement to use regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
text = "This is a sample sentence. going to checking whether it is well going. another 
sentence starting with another."

sentences = re.split('[.!?]+', text)
result = []

for s in sentences:
    words = s.split()
    if len(words) > 0 and words[0] == words[-1]:
        result.append(s.strip())

print(result)
```

Comment: It should use regex not any loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a backreference to reuse the match...

```
import re

# sample text
text = "This is a sample sentence. Well, I'll check that things are going well. another sentence starting with another. ..."

print([match[0] for match in re.findall(r"((\b\w+\b)[^.?!]+\2[.?!])", text, re.IGNORECASE)])
```

This prints...

```
['Well, I'll check that things are going well.', 'another sentence starting with another.']
```

Note: I changed the case of the first "well" to "Well" for testing purposes.

Comment: What if the text looks like this
text = "This is a sample sentence. Well, I'll check that things are going.  sentence another starting with another. ..."